# Select by Attribute all features with values that are multiples of 5?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, select-by-attribute

In my shapefile, I have a bunch of features and one field is a integer numerical attribute. I'd like to select all of the features whose value is a multiple of another value. For instance, I have a field with typical values of 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, etc. (up to 1000) and I would like to select all features with a value that is a multiple of 5.

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.

Answer (score 8):

If your tool supports it, use the [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator.

e.g. `value % 5 = 0`

... all features with a value that divides by five without a remainder.

Comment: Beat me to it!  I'll add that in ArcGIS you should use MOD ( "FIELD" ,  5)  = 0 in the select by attributes window.